# Changing numbers places in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Can anyone please learn me how to change this number 5486 to 4568 ? I need to change two pairs of numbers places. Any ideas please?

My code :

```
    public Number shiftRight(int n) {
        int length = (getNumOfDigits()+MINUSONE);
        length = (int) Math.pow(TEN, length);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            int m=num%TEN;
            num=(m*length) + (num/TEN);
        }
        return new Number(num);
    }

    public int shiftRightDistance(Number other){
        int max = getNumOfDigits();
        for (int i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
            if(compareTo(shiftRight(i))==ZERO)
            {
                return i;
            }

        }
        return MINUSONE;
    }
    public Number swapPairs() {

    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with numbers that are an odd number of digits long? Like 123?

Comment: i made a method that will get the digits number

Comment: public int getNumOfDigits(){
  int i=0;
  while (num>0){
   num=num/TEN;
   i++;
  }
  return i;
 }

 public String toString() {

  return null;
 }

 public boolean equals(Number other) {
  if (this.num == other.num){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Comment: Are you trying to sort the numbers in ascending order?

Comment: Or is it the digits in every pair must swap places?

Comment: Fine, you have a method that gets the number of digits, but that doesn't answer my question: What should the result be for a number like 123? It could be 213 (swapping pairs from the left), 132 (swapping pairs from the right), or 1032 (as if it were 0123 to start). Which do you want to be correct?

Comment: the digits in every pair must swap place like 65 will be 56 , and i just calculate the digits

Comment: 0123 to 1032(this one)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and least confusing) thing might be to convert the number to a `char` array, swap pairs of characters, and then convert back to a number. You can use `String.valueOf(int)`, `String.toCharArray()`, `new String(char[])` and `Integer.valueOf(String)` to put that together.

Alternatively, you can build on the following method that swaps the digits of a non-negative number less than 100:

```
private int swapDigitsLessThan100(int n) {
    return 10 * (n % 10) + n / 10;
}
```

The way to build on that would be to extract every pair of digits from the original number, working recursively. The following deals with numbers that are an even number of digits long:

```
public int swapDigits(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    return 100 * swapDigits(n / 100) + swapDigitsLessThan100(n % 100);
}
```

With this code, if `n` is an odd number of digits, the result will be to use a leading 0 as an additional digit.